# Geotechnical Engineering Classification and Percolation

Tags: soil-amendment, optimal-conditions, hard-landscape, hardiness-zone

I plan a project that is 4’ below ground and it’s a safe diy, I plan to place 2500lb limestone blocks for seating and don’t want them to sink or flood in the 10x10x4 hole..

Our soil classification is Blackland Prairie and the Edwards Plateau. Edwards Plateau soils are mostly shallow, stony, or gravelly, dark alkaline clays, and clay loams underlain by limestone.. and seem to have a low percolation rate, like very low it rained last week and water is still in the hole, I plan on placeing a few hidden 5’ holes back filled with gravel or a deep channel drain or such, and need engineering advice for the “base?” and drainage.

as you can tell it’s been raining so it’s filled up about 1 1/2, so the blue is where I plan to place a addition 4’ deep gravel filled hole or a dry well.

The soil looks like it’s just trash backfilled from the sub division selling the good stuff, so I plan to place 6” of 1 1/2 base to also help hide water overflow and stabilize the heavy blocks, and behind the blocks like a anti erosion retaining wall behind as well.

[image]!

[image]!

Comment: can add a site diagram so we can get an idea of what it looks like?  And can you show where you intend rainwater to go?  As in is there a lower area, a slope you can use?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added a few photos,